# Multiple assignment in R?

Tags: r, multiple-assignment

In python you can do something like this:

```py
x,y = 1,2
```

or

```
x,y = function_that_returns_two_elements()
```

I was trying to do something similar in R but found no solution. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just make the function's return value a list of length 2?

Answer (score 5):

The [zeallot](https://github.com/r-lib/zeallot) package offers an unpacking operator, `%<-%`

```
library(zeallot)

z <- list(1:3, 6:9)

c(a, b) %<-% z

a
# 1 2 3

b 
# 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use multiple assignment operator (`%=%`) for this

```
library(collapse)
c("x", "y") %=% c(1,2)
```

-output

```
> x
[1] 1
> y
[1] 2
```

---

If it should be unquoted

```
rm(x, y) # remove the objects from the global environment
.c(x, y) %=% c(1, 2)
```

-output

```
> x
[1] 1
> y
[1] 2
```